# How to change color of the top bar (including menu bar) of terminal in 18.04.3?

Tags: 18.04, themes, colors, menu-bar, top-bar

I'm using 18.04.3, how do I change the top bar and menu bar's color in terminal? I don't like the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences in the terminal.

- Go to Edit > Preferences > Unnamed > Colors

You will find how to change the color, or you can download the themes.